# How to insert an image into a tkinter sub frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

I am trying to develop a program which has a main frame (root) from which other frames are opened and closed via a menu. The main frame has an image inserted ok but as soon as I open another frame and try to insert a new image using:

```
    canvas = Canvas(date-time_window, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'yellow') 
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = moon_photo, anchor = NW)
```

I get an error pyimage2 doesnt exist, but if I remove the reference to the frame:

```
    canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'yellow')
```

the image appears in the root frame ok, but of course not in the one I want it in.

Is it possible to display images in more than one frame at a time?

I have also noticed that I get the same error with the image displayed in the main frame if I close the main frame and then re-open it with out a total restart. Again I get pyimage2 does not exist plus the canvas in the root frame  is blank.

I have read comments on how tkinter deals with garbage and suspect this could be related. I have also read a comment saying that an image should have a second reference attached to it but have not been able to see how to implement this action yet.

Can this be done within tkinter or do I need to look into using pillow instead?

Sample code, original far to long to include.

The code is called from a menu in the root window and is meant to display local date and time info. I was trying to get a picture of the present moon phase included as well:

```
def date_time():
    date_time_window = Tk()
    date_time_window.title('Date & Time')
    date_time_window.geometry('650x350')

    # Widgets

    present_date = today

    main_heading = Label(date_time_window, text = 'Date & Time')
    line1 = Canvas(date_time_window, width = 650, height = 3)
    line1.create_line(0,2 , 650,2, width = 1, fill = 'cyan')
    date_txt = Label(date_time_window,text = 'Date: ')
    date_value = Label(date_time_window, text =  today.strftime('%d') + '/' +       today.strftime('%m') + '/' + today.strftime('%y'))
    time_utc_txt = Label(date_time_window, text = 'UTC Time:')
    time_utc_value = Label(date_time_window, text = str(datetime.utcnow())[11:19])
    dls_txt = Label(date_time_window, text = 'DLS on/off: ')

    if moon_phase_number == 0:
        moon_photo = PhotoImage( file = 'images\moon_phase_0.gif')
    elif moon_phase_number == 1:
        moon_photo = PhotoImage( file = 'images\moon_phase_1.gif')


    canvas = Canvas(date_time_window, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'yellow')        
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = moon_photo, anchor = NW)

    canvas.place( x = 300, y = 150)

    close_btn.configure( command = date_time_window.destroy)

    date_time_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's `date-time_window`? Python variable names aren't usually allowed to have hyphens in them. Can you provide a [short, self contained, runnable example](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem?

Comment: Sorry hyphen was a typo from where I have been trying different solutions. Have included some cut down code. The original is far to long.

Comment: Have you tried making `moon_photo` a `global` variable, or putting it into a dictionary (filename -> photo object) that is `global`? If it is the garbage collection issue, then this should work. However, IIRC that would not cause an exception, just the image appearing as an all-blue placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

I can't debug the code sample given without a SSCCE, but I'll attempt to answer your remaining questions satisfactorily.

---

> Is it possible to display images in more than one frame at a time?

Yes, there's no particular restriction on the number of frames which may contain images.

---

> I have also read a comment saying that an image should have a second reference attached to it but have not been able to see how to implement this action yet.

That comment was probably in reference to [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) document:

> Note: When a PhotoImage object is garbage-collected by Python (e.g. when you return from a function which stored an image in a local variable), the image is cleared even if it’s being displayed by a Tkinter widget.
>
> To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object. A simple way to do this is to assign the image to a widget attribute, like this:
>
> `label = Label(image=photo)`
> `label.image = photo # keep a reference!`
> `label.pack()`

Similarly, you should attach `moon_photo` to one of your widgets. `canvas.image = moonphoto` would be sufficient.

---

> Can this be done within tkinter or do I need to look into using pillow instead?

People generally recommend PIL/Pillow for displaying images, because PhotoImage can only display gif and pgm images. PIL's `ImageTk.PhotoImage` class supports many more kinds of formats. However, since you're only trying to render gifs here, you don't need anything other than Tkinter.

Comment: Tried both suggestions neither worked. Will try Pillow instead.